# Shortest path in a graph ( how to return to origin ? )

Tags: c#, algorithm, google-maps-api-3, graph, shortest-path

I'm working on a project for a transport company. Essentially I get, let's say , 200 city's and 7 trucks and I need to compute best weight distribution over the 7 trucks and the shortest path overall (km).

Before I actually communicate with Google Maps API I do my own computation. For 7 trucks I can compute about 30 milion routes in about 2 hours. ( weight distribution is done with backtracking / dynamic programing and "next city" is chosed with some math formulas )

I need to compare those routes and remember the best one ( smallest km over the 7 trucks ).

I get something like this :

```
Truck 1
    City 1 (x,y)
    City 2 (x,y)
    City 3 (x,y)
    City 4 (x,y)
    .....

Truck 2
    City 1 (x,y)
    City 2 (x,y)
    City 3 (x,y)
    City 4 (x,y)
    .....

Truck 3
    City 1 (x,y)
    City 2 (x,y)
    City 3 (x,y)
    City 4 (x,y)
    .....

etc ...
```

Where (x,y) are longitude and latitude. I can compute the distance between each city with the Euclidean distance **d = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)** so I end up with a graph.

> I was thinking to use A* algorithm to order the city's of each truck
>   and after get the distance between the ordered city's. The problem is
>   that in real life the trucks are going to return to the starting point
>   ... can A* take that in to account ?

I am aware that the shortest path in longitude/latitude will not always be the shortest in km , but is OK, let's say 90% accuracy will do.

> Any idea how I can compute a "score" for each route ( all 7 trucks )
>   so it can map as close as possible to the actual km ?

( I can do limited calls to Google Maps API and I want to rule out the worst options locally )

Comment: Have a look at the breadth-first and depth-first algorithms.

Comment: If Google Maps licens pricing is a problem, why not have a look at OpenStreetMap.org.

Comment: The Euclidean distance isn't correct because longitude degrees are not equal to latitude degrees except near the equator. You will do better with a great circle calculation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula

Comment: Thank you . Now I realize that I really needed this